# Publicly available webservice I can use

Tags: php, rest, webservice-client, webservices-client

I am learning to write PHP client programs which call webservices with POST & GET. Is there any publicly available webservice I can use for trying out client programs? Basically, I don't want to get into writing a webservice first before I start trying out client programs - are there any such easy to use webservices I can use?

Comment: What are these client programs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can browse through [ProgrammableWeb's API directory (REST protocol)](http://www.programmableweb.com/apis/directory/1?protocol=REST). What kind of webservice are you looking for in particular?

Comment: I am looking for some practice in writing client programs in php-cli & curl which make both HTTP & HTTPS POSTs & GETs to webservices. I am looking for both tutorials in this and also public webservices against which I can make these calls.